# Let LVM+LUKS volume grow over new drive or RAID?

Tags: encryption, raid, lvm, luks

I would like to extend the storage capacity on my Ubuntu server by adding more drives.

I'm currently using LVM+LUKS on my server and I'm having some difficulty understanding how I may add new drives to the existing LVM volume without having to re-install the whole system. From what I understand that's the reason of using LVM - extending the storage capacity on the fly -pretty much.

But how do I do this if the volume also in encrypted? Is it even possible since, from what I understand, the LUKS actually pretty static from the initial capacity?

I have two drives set up as a software RAID 0 that I'd like to use in the current running system volume, using only one additions disk.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cryptsetup` to initialize a partition on the new disk as another LUKS volume ( you will now have to supply both passphrases at boot time to unlock ), and then use `pvcreate` to initialize the new LUKS device as an LVM physical volume.  Then `vgextend` to add that volume to the volume group, and finally you can use `lvconvert` to convert your existing logical volumes to raid0, which will stripe them between the two drives.  You probably will also want to use `lvextend` to increase the size of the logical volume, and `resize2fs` to expand the filesystem on it to use the additional space.

Comment: That is a whole lot of steps. Maybe I should just reinstall my system. But thank you so much for the info!

Comment: @DanielHolm, it does take a few steps, but the good thing is they can run in the background without interrupting your work.